# how to set textview in a service?

Tags: android

I have an activity that has 2 button(start, end), when the user presses start, the activity will fire a service that record the voice and save it when the user presses end button. And to make sure that the user know he is recording, I add a textview on the activity UI and hope that the service class can change it to something like "it is recording..." on the service's onStartCommand() and "Finished record" on the onDestory() . But since Service class doesn't support findviewbyId(), how do I solve this problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish that would be to use a Toast notification, which can be created and displayed from a service- here's the documentation on Toasts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

According to that page, this example demonstrates everything you need for most toast notifications. You should rarely need anything else:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Comment: The problem about using a toast is that it will not last on the page.
For example, if the user presses the button start and go to do other stuff for a while, after he comes back, he might forgot if the app is still recording because the toast disappear already

Comment: That is true. Sorry- from your first question I thought you just wanted to display a quick message to the user. But in this case, have you thought about using a Status Bar Notification?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

That way, the message regarding the apps current activity would be right there in that drag-down status bar menu when the user goes to navigate back to your app, so that may be the best place for the notice anyway, and it's another method that is possible from a service, without needing to find a view.